# Finding perspective angle using vanishing points

Tags: geometry

Assume i drew a square on a sheet of paper.

If I look at the paper from a different perspective, I assume it is possible to find the angle from which I am looking by using the vanishing points, which is faintly marked with the green dots in the illustration.

[image: Illustration]

I found inspiration in the article "Using Vanishing Points for Camera Calibration" by Caprile and Torre, but I cannot seem to get the angles right.

I suspect there is a simple solution to this, am I missing something obvious?

The source is camera images, with known Focal Length and fixed square dimensions

Comment: you are assuming a "pinhole camera"? which angle do you mean? (the angle of the main ray with the plane of the rectangle?)

Comment: Yes, I am assuming a pinhole camera. The main angle of interest is the elevation, i.e. in which angle am I looking down on the paper. So yes, main ray with the rectangle plane :)